# Button to start python script that contains infinite loop

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm not very experienced at node js.  I have a submit button that triggers the function just following the comment "//Insert" in index.js.  The problem is that the python script that is called in that function has an infinite loop which, consequently doesn't allow that add page to finish or do anything for that matter.  Is there a way for the function to start the script and then just redirect the client back to the page where the button was clicked?

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
const fs = require('fs');
const requestIp = require('request-ip');
var helmet = require('helmet');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { exec } = require("child_process");

// App setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(4000, function(){
    console.log('listening for requests on port 4000,');
});

// Static files
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
// Socket setup & pass server
var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);
    // Handle chat event

    //const ip = socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
     var ip = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress.split(':')[3];
    console.log(ip);
     io.to(socket.id).emit('remIp',ip);

});


//watch the talon json info

fs.watchFile("talon.json", (curr, prev) => {
  console.log("\nThe File was modified");
  console.log("Previous Modification Time", prev.mtime);
  console.log("Current Modification Time", curr.mtime);

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('talon.json');
if(rawdata != null){
  try{
    let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    io.sockets.emit('mavlink',data);
    }
  catch (e){
    console.log("The error is:  ", e);
  }
}
});


// Insert
app.post('/add', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.gsip);
    console.log(req.body.gsp);
exec("sudo python3 /home/pi/MAVProxy/MAVProxy/mavproxy.py --master=/dev/serial0 --baudrate 921600 --aircraft NanoTalon --out " + req.body.gsip + ":" + req.body.gsp + " &>/home/pi/latestLog.log", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});


});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>Loren's Nano Talon Powered by Ardupilot</title>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
                <div id="header">
                <h1>Nano Talon Home</h1>
            <h2>Loren Zimmer</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Design</a></li>
              <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="leftmenu">

        <div id="leftmenu_top"></div>

                                <div id="leftmenu_main">

                <h3>System</h3>

                <ul>
                    <div id="mavlink-output">
                    <li><a href="#">Waiting for updates</a></li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
</div>


              <div id="leftmenu_bottom"></div>
        </div>




                <div id="content">


        <div id="content_top"></div>
        <div id="content_main">
                <h2>Main information </h2>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <h3>Ground Station Information</h3>

                <p><form action="/add" method="post">
<label for="gsip">IP to send ground station information to:</label>
<input type="text" id="gsip" name="gsip"><br><br></p>
<label for="gsp">Port to send ground station information to:</label>
<input type="text" id="gsp" name="gsp" value="14550"><br><br></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
<h3>More information</h3>
                <p>I decided to leave the content portion open for the templates users to do as they wish with a blank canvas. I don't like to restrict my users too much, and for this reason I leave the defining of any content related styles to you.</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <h3>Template Notes</h3>
            <p>The main image can be changed by either replacing the current image with another one of the same size (900x402), or using a new one of what ever dimensions you'd like.  If you choose the latter, you must open up style.css and change the dimensions of #mainpic, as well as the file name if that is different. If you would like to move the heading around in the above image, find &quot;#mainpic h1&quot; in style.css and modify it's &quot;left&quot; and &quot;top&quot; properties, this is also true for the h2 tag.</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id="list"></div>
        <div id="content_bottom"></div>

            <div id="footer"><h3><a href="http://www.bryantsmith.com">florida web design</a></h3></div>
      </div>
   </div>

<script src="/talon.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried using `setTimeout` to push the `exec` call to its own thread?

Comment: use `nohup [command] &` to launch a process in the background so that exec returns immidiatly.

Comment: @wuerfelfreak the nohup was just what I needed.  Thanks so much

Comment: I added my comment as an answer. Please accept it as solution. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a blocking command in `bash` in a non-blocking way, you can use the `nohup` command. `nohup` makes sure, that the command continues running even when the `session` is closed. To make it non-blocking, add a `&` at the end. The command is then started in the background and `exec` returns imidiately.

```
exec("nohup command &")
```

applied to your situation it looks like this:

```
exec("nohup sudo python3 /home/pi/MAVProxy/MAVProxy/mavproxy.py --master=/dev/serial0 --baudrate 921600 --aircraft NanoTalon --out " + req.body.gsip + ":" + req.body.gsp + " &>/home/pi/latestLog.log")
```